# It is possible to use QTGMC deinterlacing with FFmpeg?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video-editing, avisynth

I'am using the [media-autobuild_suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite) (on Windows). [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4PyyQoz6eo) tutorial describes how to install and use [QTGMC](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/QTGMC) with [AviSynth+](https://avs-plus.net). My question is can one use `FFmpeg` **only** to deinterlace video files with `QTGMC`?

Since working with `QTGMC` is based on commands (like it does `FFmpeg`), as shown in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4PyyQoz6eo) between [39:12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4PyyQoz6eo&t=2352s) and [1:11:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4PyyQoz6eo&t=4260s) and `AviSynth+` is already part of the `media-autobuild_suite`, see

[image: AviSynth+]

the idea suggests itself: Why one shouldn't use `FFmpeg` for this task instead? This means to use `FFmpeg` to instruct `QTGMC` what is to do on a given video file. Than one could avoid the weird installation of `QTGMC` and `AviSynth+`, as shown in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4PyyQoz6eo) between [04:01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4PyyQoz6eo&t=241s) and [39:12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4PyyQoz6eo&t=2352s).

So, is the above possible and if yes, how?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!